# What happens if full thrust is applied at cruise altitude for 5-10 minutes on a 787?

Tags: boeing-787, cruise

What happens when you apply full throttle to the engines of a Boeing 787 at cruise altitude for 5-10 minutes?

Other than wasting fuel, what maximum speeds are reached?

Does that pose any danger or damage to the airframe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Autopilot flying straight and level**

Upon reaching the VMO/MMO the A/P will be inhibited from trimming down any further, which will result in the airplane climbing at the VMO/MMO.

> Overspeed protection limits the speed to which the airplane can be trimmed. At VMO/MMO, the trim reference speed is limited by inhibiting trim in the nose down direction.

**Hand flying straight and level**

Pushing the thrust levers forward will result in a climb at the current speed due to the fly-by-wire design—only the trim buttons change the "trim reference speed".

> Once the column forces are trimmed to zero, the airplane maintains a constant speed with no column inputs. Thrust changes result in a relatively constant indicated airspeed climb or descent.

---

Source: Boeing 787 FCOM chapters 4 and 9.

Further reading:

- [What does the term "trimming" most commonly mean in aviation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/164/14897)
- [Why does overspeed cause structural damage or failure when limit load factors are not exceeded?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36012/14897)
- [How does envelope protection work in Airbus vs. Boeing aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44430/14897)
- [How does auto-trim work on fly-by-wire aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16927/14897)

Comment: So basically setting full thrust will put you in the coffin corner eventually rather than overspeeding? Interesting choice.

Comment: @Sanchises - Sure, if the crew want to ignore the caution light, the beeper, the `autopilot` EICAS message, and not having pitch command bars :)

Comment: You could hold a forward input on the control column to speed up beyond VMO/MMO instead of having the aircraft climb with zero control column force.